# Does the Redliner quality affect your attributes or your cyberlimbs' attributes?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

I decided to create a character from *Chrome Flesh* who used the Redliner positive quality, providing +1 Str/Agi for every 2 full cyberarms/legs. So of course I get myself two chrome arms and legs. Now the tricky part:

> Cyberlimbs: These prosthetics are basic off-the-shelf models. All standard cyberlimbs come with Strength and Agility attributes of 3. These values can only be augmented by cyberlimb enhancements, not other augmentations.
>
> — pg 456 core

Does that mean the bonus from the quality applies to my base attribute scores? Not for the cyberlimbs. Wouldn't that make the quality useless by replacing all your limbs?

Answer (score 6):

There currently does not seem to be errata for Chrome Flesh, but the German version often contains clarifications that could be considered semi-official. (Translators repeatedly stated that such things require approval of CGL in the forums.)

The German version contains the following clarification:

> [...] bis maximal jeweils +2 auf beide Attribute (dies gilt sowohl für die natürlichen Attribute des Charakters als auch für seine Cybergliedmaßenattribute)

English translation

> [...] up to the maximum of +2 for each attribute (this applies to the natural attributes of the character as **well as to his cyber limb attributes**)